# Freebsd jail command execution error with no reason

Tags: freebsd, jail

I try to execute command:

```
# service jail start myjail
```

I debug the /etc/rc.d/jail and dump that really command is:

```
/usr/sbin/jail -l -U root -i -f /var/run/jail.myjail.conf -c myjail
```

The output is:

> ```
> usage: jail [-dhilqv] [-J jid_file] [-u username] [-U username]
>             -[cmr] param=value ... [command=command ...]
>        jail [-dqv] [-f file] -[cmr] [jail]
>        jail [-qv] [-f file] -[rR] ['*' | jail ...]
>        jail [-dhilqv] [-J jid_file] [-u username] [-U username]
>             [-n jailname] [-s securelevel]
>             path hostname [ip[,...]] command ...
> ```

The file /var/run/jail.myjail.conf is autogenrated by rc jail script based on variables of previously worked jail from rc.conf

The content is:

```
myjail {
        host.hostname = "myjail.example.com";
        path = "/var/jail/myjail.root";
        ip4.addr += "192.168.0.150/32";
        allow.raw_sockets = 0;
        exec.clean;
        exec.system_user = "root";
        exec.jail_user = "root";
        exec.start += "/bin/sh /etc/rc";
        exec.stop = "/bin/sh /etc/rc.shutdown";
        exec.consolelog = "/var/log/jail_myjail_console.log";
        mount.devfs;
        allow.set_hostname = 0;
        allow.sysvipc = 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by replace old style configuration variables in `rc.conf` by one line:

```
jail_myjail_conf="/var/run/jail.myjail.conf"
```